# Using Builder with Promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, builder

I have a Builder class which has a load function: (important to note that I can't change the loaders load function)

```
class Builder {
    constructor() {
        this.object = {};
    }

    async load(url) {
        this.object = await this.loadPromise(url);
        return this;
    }

    loadPromise(url) {
        return Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(new Loader().load(url));
        }
    }
    
    build() {
        return this.object;
    }

}
```

When I try to call a full build chain I get an Error:

> (intermediate Object).load(...).build is not a function

My function chain: `var object = new Builder().load('someurl.com').build();`

When I call: `var object = new Builder().load('someurl.com');` and then `console.log(object);` the logged object is of type builder and has the correct object loaded.

I want to be able to call functions on the Builder after loading the object. This includes functions which need to modify the loaded object.
I am searching for a pleasing semantic solution and not a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem of timing. Try this:

```
var object = (await (new Builder().load('someurl.com'))).build();
```

In the Builder class, the `load` function is async and therefore returns a Promise object. In your original code, you are trying to access the `build()` method of a Promise object, which is not defined.